# Typehint list with strings and lists of strings in mypy

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

How would one type hint the following:

```py
def f(x : <type>) -> None: print(x)
```

Where `x` is a list containing strings, and lists of strings.

Eg:

```
# example 1
['a', 'sdf', ['sd', 'sdg'], 'oidsf d', 'as', ['asf','asr']]
# example 2
[['as', 'asfd'], ['oei', 'afgdf'], 'egt', 'aergaer']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you want is `Union`:

```
from typing import List, Union


def f(x: List[Union[str, List[str]]]) -> None:
    print(x)


f(['a', 'sdf', ['sd', 'sdg'], 'oidsf d', 'as', ['asf', 'asr']])
f([['as', 'asfd'], ['oei', 'afgdf'], 'egt', 'aergaer'])
```

A `List[Union[str, List[str]]]` is "a list of items that can be either strings or lists of strings".